# How do make a CSS grid with horizontal overflow?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm building a 4-column layout with CSS grid. When the browser's width hits a a specific break point (aka: mobile device) I want the first column to be fixed to the left side of the browser (X-axis. I'm currently using min-content to determine the max width the column is) and the remaining columns then scroll under.

You can see this behavior in **Amazon's mobile compare feature**. Scroll down [this page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07X6C9RMF) to the section labeled "*Compare Blink Cameras*". You'll see that the first column is locked and the rest of the products scroll under the first column as you swipe left.)

My code structure is like this (simplified):

```css
.container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: 1fr;
grid-column-gap: 5px;
grid-row-gap: 0px;
}

.item1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; background:yellowgreen;}
.item2 { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; background:#ddd }
.item3 { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4; background:#ddd}

.item1,.item2,.item3 {padding: 1rem;}
```

```html
<p>THIS IS THE DESCRIPTION OF THE PRODUCT FEATURE IN EACH COLUMN</p>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">FEATURE 1 : TO BE STICKY</div>
  <div class="item2">FEATURE 2 : Scrolls under #1</div>
  <div class="item3">FEATURE 3 : Scrolls under #1</div>
</div>
```

**How do I get the first column to stay locked and the others scroll under?**

Comment: Consider putting the first column in a separate container with `position: fixed`. Put the remaining three columns in the grid container.

Comment: Hummm, I feel that's going to make editing this a small nightmare. :(    I'm hoping there's a different solution.

Comment: I appreciate the desire to provide simplified code, but what we need is a [mcve].

Comment: Argh.. Can't get the little code demo to run. @TylerH how do I do this correctly?

Comment: @JPFotoz Click "Edit" at the bottom, and then click "edit the above snippet" in the editor preview section.

Comment: @TylerH -- thanks! I updated it to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:sticky` will work here.

```css
.grid{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width:400px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
.col{
  width:200px;
}
.left{
  position:sticky;
  left:0;
  z-index:999;
  background:lightgray;
}
```

```html
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="left">
      Description
    </div>
    <div class = "col">
      Column 1
    </div>
    <div class = "col">
      Column 2
    </div>
    <div class = "col">
      Colunm 3
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If you only need support for the current version of the major browsers, `position: sticky` is a good option. https://caniuse.com/?search=sticky

Comment: @Quasipickle Follow up question.  I've discovered that when the viewport is narrow (use dom inspector to view this page around 500px)  that the scroll bars appear in an outer container. This causes the 'sticky' element to move off screen to the left.    How can this be locked for mobile devices?

Comment: My initial thought is that that is due to a setting in an outer container.  Could you link to a Codepen with a reduced example?